# How to change content mode on AVPlayer video?

Tags: swift

My problem is that when I'm displaying video it's bigger than my screen size. Maybe the problem is not content mode but wrong frame bounds or something.

```
let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"videkas", withExtension: "mp4")

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer.volume = 0
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    avPlayerLayer.frame = (featureView13?.bounds)!
    featureView13?.backgroundColor = .clear
    featureView13?.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: avPlayer.currentItem)
```

**I also tried `avPlayerLayer.frame = (featureView13?.layer.bounds)!` but no luck.**

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you
https://gist.github.com/jkosoy/c835fea2c03e76720c77

Call this method when your video started buffering

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let size = CGSize.aspectFit(aspectRatio: self. avPlayerLayer.frame.size, boundingSize: self.view.frame.size)
    self.avPlayerLayerHeightContraint.constant = size.height
    self.avPlayerLayer.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Hope you get
the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Change `resizeAspectFill` to `resizeAspect`. There is a big difference!

Answer (score -1):

use AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFit to fit the video in the screen:

```
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFit
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using,

```
avPlayerLayer.frame = (featureView13?.bounds)!
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
avPlayerLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
```